# How to print values from a file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file and its content is something like this:

```
A:3
B:5
C:7
A:8
C:6
```

I need to print:

```
A numbers: 3, 8
B numbers: 5
C numbers: 7, 6
```

I'm a beginner so if you could give some help I would appreciate it. I have made a dictionary but that's pretty much all I know.

Comment: Please show the code you have to make the dictionary and what went wrong. It's much easier to help you that way and address why your approach was not successful. There's plenty of questions/answers in this area already.

Comment: I feel like this question across my feed at least once a week. The answer is `collections.defaultdict(list)` or just `some_dict.setdefault(letter, []).append(number)`. Then someone smart thinks of sorting the input and applying `itertools.groupby`, which may or may not be faster.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an approach that keeps the values in a dictionary:

```
d = {}                       # create an empty dictionary
for line in open(filename):  # opens the file
    k, v = line.split(':')   # unpack each line in the char before : and after
    if k in d:               # add the values to the dictionary
        d[k].append(v)
    else:
        d[k] = [v]
```

This gives you a dictionary containing your file in a format that you can utilize to get the desired output:

```
for key, values in sorted(d.items()):   
    print(key, 'numbers:' ', '.join(values))
```

The `sorted` is required because dictionaries are unordered.

---

Note that using `collections.defaultdict` instead of a normal `dict` could simplify the approach somewhat. The:

```
 d = {}

 ...

    if k in d:               # add the values to the dictionary
        d[k].append(v)
    else:
        d[k] = [v]
```

could then be replaced by:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

...

    d[k].append(v)
```

Comment: It isn't a guarantee the sorted order is the desired order. I would suggest an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Correct, but using `OrderedDict` prevents using `defaultdict`. It's a bit of a dilemma there :(

Comment: you can replace `if k in d:` and onward in a standard dict with `d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ do we think it's more likely that the data should appear in its "first seen" order in the file, or alphabetically? I'd lay my money on the latter.

Comment: @AdamSmith The latter satisfies only a subset of problems that the former does. ;)

Comment: @MSeifert You can use the `setdefault` thingy for the best of both worlds!

Comment: `OrderedDict` just seems overkill to me for this solution. YMMV :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You're right about `setdefault`. I'm just a bit hesitant to change it because I think in it's current form it addresses the question without introducing too many (optimization-) choices to a (self-declared) beginner. Also it's not clear to me if "order-of-appearance" or "sorted" is correct (both would answer it correctly).

Comment: How is OrderedDict overkill but not defaultdict when you can just use setdefault? Geez...

Answer (score 0):

Short version (Which should sort in alphabetic order)

```
d = {}      
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('filename.txt')]
[d.setdefault(line[0], []).append(line[2]) for line in lines]
[print(key, 'numbers:', ', '.join(values)) for key,values in sorted(d.items())]
```

Or if you want to maintain the order as they appear in file (file order)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict() # Empty dict
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('filename.txt')] # Get the lines
[d.setdefault(line[0], []).append(line[2]) for line in lines] # Add lines to dictionary
[print(key, 'numbers:', ', '.join(values)) for key,values in d.items()] # Print lines
```

Tested with Python 3.5.

Answer (score -1):

You can treat your file as csv (comma separated value) so you can use the `csv` module to parse the file in one line. Then use `defaultdict` with input in the costructor the class `list` to say that to create it when the key not exists. Then use `OrderedDict` class because standard dictionary don't keeps the order of your keys.

```
import csv
from collection import defaultdict, OrderedDict    
values = list(csv.reader(open('your_file_name'), delimiter=":")) #[['A', '3'], ['B', '5'], ['C', '7'], ['A', '8'], ['C', '6']]
dct_values = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in values:
    dct_values[k].append(v)
dct_values = OrderedDict(sorted(dct_values.items()))
```

Then you can simply print iterating the dictionary.
A very easy way to group by key is by external library, if you are interested try PyFunctional